Using lambda function for command option in GUI Button Constructor
My question is regarding the use of the lambda function in the syntax used to create GUI Buttons for this Python calculator below.
QUESTION:  My understanding of how to write a lambda function is as follows in 1), so how is it possible write it in the way it is written in the command option of the GUI Button constructor as follows in 2)?
The full code for the calculator is below.  The video for this Python Calculator tutorial is found here:  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UQZNHlaUVc&list=PLZPZq0r_RZOOkUQbat8LyQii36cJf2SWT&index=113)
1)
>>> add_one = lambda x: x + 1
>>> add_one(2)




button1 = Button(frame,text=1,height=4,width=9,font=35,
             command=lambda: button_press(1))

from tkinter import *

def button_press(num):                          
    global equation_text   

    equation_text = equation_text + str(num)  
    equation_label.set(equation_text)

def equals():
    global equation_text

    try:
        total = str(eval(equation_text))
        equation_label.set(total)
        equation_text = total   
    except SyntaxError:
        equation_label.set("syntax error")
        equation_text = ""           
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        equation_label.set("arithmetic error")
        equation_text = ""

def clear():
    global equation_text

    equation_label.set("")
    equation_text = ""         

window = Tk()                       
window.title("Calculator program")                  
window.geometry("500x500")                      

equation_text = ""
equation_label = StringVar()
label = Label(window, textvariable=equation_label, font=('consolas',
20),bg='white',width=24,height=2)
label.pack()
frame = Frame(window)
frame.pack()

button1 = Button(frame,text=1,height=4,width=9,font=35,
                 command=lambda: button_press(1))
button1.grid(row=0,column=0)

button2 = Button(frame,text=2,height=4,width=9,font=35,
                 command=lambda: button_press(2))
button2.grid(row=0,column=1)

button3 = Button(frame,text=3,height=4,width=9,font=35,
                 command=lambda: button_press(3))
button3.grid(row=0,column=2)

button4 = Button(frame,text=4,height=4,width=9,font=35,
             command=lambda: button_press(4))
button4.grid(row=1,column=0)

button5 = Button(frame,text=5,height=4,width=9,font=35,
                 command=lambda: button_press(5))
button5.grid(row=1,column=1)

button6 = Button(frame,text=6,height=4,width=9,font=35,
                 command=lambda: button_press(6))
button6.grid(row=1,column=2)

button7 = Button(frame,text=7,height=4,width=9,font=35,
                 command=lambda: button_press(7))
button7.grid(row=2,column=0)

button8 = Button(frame,text=8,height=4,width=9,font=35,
                 command=lambda: button_press(8))
button8.grid(row=2,column=1)

button9 = Button(frame,text=9,height=4,width=9,font=35,
                 command=lambda: button_press(9))
button9.grid(row=2,column=2)

button0 = Button(frame,text=0,height=4,width=9,font=35,
                 command=lambda: button_press(0))
button0.grid(row=3,column=0)

plus = Button(frame,text='+',height=4,width=9,font=35,
                 command=lambda: button_press('+'))
plus.grid(row=0,column=3)

minus = Button(frame,text='-',height=4,width=9,font=35,
                 command=lambda: button_press('-'))
minus.grid(row=1,column=3)

multiply = Button(frame,text='*',height=4,width=9,font=35,
                 command=lambda: button_press('*'))
multiply.grid(row=2,column=3)

divide = Button(frame,text='/',height=4,width=9,font=35,
                 command=lambda: button_press('/'))
divide.grid(row=3, column=3)

equal = Button(frame,text='=',height=4,width=9,font=35,
                 command=equals)
equal.grid(row=3,column=2)

decimal = Button(frame,text='.',height=4,width=9,font=35,
                 command=lambda: button_press('.'))
decimal.grid(row=3,column=1)

clear = Button(window,text='clear',height=4,width=9,font=35,
                 command=clear)
clear.pack()

window.mainloop()

My understanding is it has to be written close to this for it to work, but can't explain why:
command=lambda num: button_press(1)


Lambda functions should not be used when you need side effects on a global variable. Use a named function.

Hello Barmar.  Thanks - could help me better understand.  I used a named function (button_press(num)) with lambda - or am I not understanding your response?

use def to define a named function. Then you can use global to declare the global variable that will be updated.

There is no such thing as a "lambda function". Lambda expressions are just a simpler way to create the same kind of function that a def statement creates. (Lambda expressions are simply limited to, well, a single expression to use as the return value, whereas def statements can use an arbitrarily long sequence of statements to compute the return value.)

@chepner, thanks and sorry for using the wrong terminology.  Based on how the lambda expression is written in the code above, this seems to be a departure from how lambda expressions are created.  Why is a lambda expression used in this instance? :
‘command=lambda: button_press(1))’?

The parameter list is optional, if that's your concern: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda

This question is similar to: How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
